# How do I access a subclass's functions using namespaces?

Tags: php, oop

So, I have a few classes I'm trying to use PHP's namespaces with and am having some trouble accessing the functions in the lowest level class.

Here's how it's laid out...

`Activity -> Post`

`Activity` has a namespace of `activity` and `Post` has a namespace of `post`

At the top of my Post class I have this code.

```
namespace Post;
use activity\activity;
```

That's the code that PHPStorm created when I made my class file and then extended my Activity class.

So, when I try to access my public functions inside Post, I have tried both of these methods...

```
\activity\post::function();
```

AND

```
$post = new \activity\post();
$post->function();
```

But PHPStorm tells me neither of those exist.

So, what's the actual way to access these lower level functions?

I've googled quite a bit but apparently I'm not searching for the right thing because I haven't found anything about sub classes.

Thanks so much for your help in understanding how this works.

Comment: Your namespace for `Post` doesn't look right. Your class name determines the final term in a PHP namespace reference, and the namespace are all the terms before it. For example, you'd do `namespace AppName;` and then class name of `class Post { ...`, then refer to it using `use AppName\Post;`

Comment: Ok, so I don't even need to setup a namespace for Post then. The extension will automatically add it to that I guess. Thanks!

Comment: See the edit to my comment. Also check out [namespace basics](http://www.sitepoint.com/php-53-namespaces-basics/) and [PHP docs on namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php)

Comment: Appreciate it! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `\activity`, use `activity`.

`\activity` is using the `\` (or base) namespace.

Use doesn't extend a class, it creates an alias.  Since you have `Use activity\activity` this makes it so you can access functions in the `activity` class by running `activity::function()` rather than using the full namespace `\activity\activity::function()`.

You can also define `use \activity\activity as test` and access functions like `test::function()`.

I'm not sure of the point of having the namespaces the same name as the classes though but sjagr addressed that in comments.

Comment: Ok, so to access the functions in Post I would use `activity\post::function()` - is that correct?

Comment: @Mark I added some more information in my post after reading your question more thoroughly.